# jQuery Autocomplete convert Multiple Inputs into Tag and Save

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

My code for autocomplete is same as its [here](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#multiple-remote). It allows autocompleting multiple values into a single field. I have change

The code

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jQuery UI Autocomplete - Multiple, remote</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<style>
.ui-autocomplete-loading {
background: white url("images/ui-anim_basic_16x16.gif") right center no-repeat;
}
</style>
<script>
$(function() {
function split( val ) {
return val.split( /,\s*/ );
}
function extractLast( term ) {
return split( term ).pop();
}
$( "#birds" )
// don't navigate away from the field on tab when selecting an item
.bind( "keydown", function( event ) {
if ( event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB &&
$( this ).autocomplete( "instance" ).menu.active ) {
event.preventDefault();
}
})
.autocomplete({
source: function( request, response ) {
$.getJSON( "search.php", {
term: extractLast( request.term )
}, response );
},
search: function() {
// custom minLength
var term = extractLast( this.value );
if ( term.length < 2 ) {
return false;
}
},
focus: function() {
// prevent value inserted on focus
return false;
},
select: function( event, ui ) {
var terms = split( this.value );
// remove the current input
terms.pop();
// add the selected item
terms.push( ui.item.value );
// add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end
terms.push( "" );
this.value = terms.join( ", " );
return false;
}
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="ui-widget">
<label for="birds">Birds: </label>
<input id="birds" size="50">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The json data passed is in below format.

`[{"EMMPLOYEENAME":"John Doe","EMPLOYEEID":"123"}]`

1. The list does not show anything when I type something.
2. How can I convert searched input values into `Tags`
3. Is it possible to save those multiple values when user submits the
   form ?

How can I modify autocompleting multiple values to address above issues ?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you add your code.

Comment: Please format the code properly so that it is readable. What exactly do you mean by *"save those multiple values when user submits the form"* ? Save where..?

Comment: Save it in DB, whereas they would be viewed as tags.